# Simple Injector configuration with a DbContext in a console application

Tags: simple-injector

**EDIT:** 
I will give it another try. Below is all of the pertinent code:

```
  //in BaseProject for other console apps (a class library):
    public class SimpleInjectorInitializer
    {
      public static Container MakeContainer()
      {
        Container container = new Container()
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ThreadScopedLifestyle(); //Also tried with asyncScopedLifestyle, various combinations of these two
    container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = new ThreadScopedLifestyle();

    container.Register<MyRoot>();
    container.Register<ISomeOther, SomeOtherStuff>()
    //etc.

   container.Register<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

   container.Verify();

   return container;    
  }
}

//In DependentConsoleApp, which references the above project:
class Program
{
  private static Container _container;

  static Program
  {
    _container = SimpleInjectorInitializer.MakeContainer();
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var myRoot = _container.GetInstance<MyRoot>();
  myRoot.DoStuff();
}
```

In addition to the two above classes being in different projects, the interfaces and their implementations are in different projects, and the DbContexts and their interfaces are in different projects.

At the call to `_container.GetInstance<>()`, I get the following exception and stack trace:

```
SimpleInjector.ActivationException: 'The MyRoot is registered as 'Thread Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Thread Scoped) scope.'

   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration)
   at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration, Scope scope)
   at SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`1.GetInstance(Scope scope)
```

When I try AsyncScopedLifestyle, I get the same exception.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. Your current example doesn't demonstrate the problem. And please post a full stack trace.

Comment: @Steven added stack trace.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consoleintegration.html)? It does a fairly good job in describing your scenario. If, after reading the docs, you still have any questions, please describe what is not working, and post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @Steven I did read the documentation, and I believe I'm doing it as advised. (Based on exceptions I was getting I added the default lifestyles.) I've tried again, from scratch. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "complete and verifiable" example, but all of the relevant code is above.

Comment: You have got two options. 1: don't use Scoped, but Singleton, since your console application seems short-lived, or 2: wrap the resolve around a ` (ThreadScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)` call, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: @Steven Since this is a long-running application, I tried your second suggestion, and it worked. Thanks for your time. If you are in the mood to post it as an answer, I'll gladly give it the big green check mark.

Comment: Aint nobody got time for that, @RobC :). If you wish, you may answer your own question.